# Excel VBA drop down list and vlookup issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a VBA code that will create a drop down list or have a Vlookup function in a cell.
I am new to VBA so please have mercy. :)
The problem is that with the code below it always crashes Excel.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Lookup_Range As Range

Set shList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ListaEchipamente")
Set Lookup_Range = shList.Range("G10", "M345")

If Cells(Target.Row, 13).Value = " " Then

With Range("J2:J100").Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=ListaEchipamente!K10:K345"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With

ElseIf Not Cells(Target.Row, 13).Value = " " Then

Cells(Target.Row, 10).Value = "=VLookup(Range(target.row, 13), Lookup_Range, 2, False)"

End If

End Sub
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you have a target range indicated? Right now, any time there is a change in the worksheet, the code activates, Possible, if your target column is A then you could start your code like,`if target.count>1 then exit sub` `if target.column<>1 then exit sub` `your code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code changing `Cells(Target.Row, 10).Value` triggers another Change event and you get endless loop. To avoid it disable events first:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

'code to modify cells here 

Application.EnableEvents = True
```